# Mergesort: Dynamically Allocating an Array with Size Known Only at Runtime

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

i'm taking an algorithms class and was trying to implement a merge sort in c++. I was trying to store a left and right subarray but realize i was unable to do so because I can't initialize size at runtime. Is there a way to get around this or am I going about the sorting process incorrectly? I listed what I have below.

I'm also trying to avoid vectors because that's too obvious and easy.

```
void merge(int *arr, int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int size1 = mid - left + 1;
    int size2 = right - mid;

    int leftArr[size1];
    int rightArr[size2];
    ....

}
void mergeSort(int *arr, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, mid+1, right);
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `int *leftArr` and use [`new []`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/) and `delete []`. Even better, familiarize yourself with [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). You write you're coding in C++, but this is really C.

Comment: *I'm also trying to avoid vectors because that's too obvious and easy.* -- What's wrong with using something that's obvious?  It doesn't win points by making the code harder than it should be.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, not trying to make it harder. more for the learning experience. I know it's possible with vectors and I can definitely do it with vectors. Unfortunately schooling doesn't work that way. gotta learn how the professor wants it done.

Comment: @AmiTavory, thanks I will try that out. Also C syntax is very similar to C++. This is indeed C++ though.

Comment: Well, we don't know what your school wants or not.  The obvious answer to dynamic array in C++ is use vector.  Also, you still have to implement the merge sort -- using vector only helps in that you don't worry about leaks or pointer mismanagement.  Using vector doesn't magically create a merge sort function for you.  As to learning, why oh why don't teachers just have you create a dynamic array class and then use that in further assignments?

Comment: You might want to consider making a helper / entry function so that only a one time allocation of a temp buffer is used, and then passed as a parameter to mergeSort and in turn merge. This way the functions are just working with indices and moving data using the pre-allocated temp buffer and the original array. Is a top down merge sort part of the requirement? If not another alternative would be a bottom up merge sort which doesn't use recursion.

Comment: Do you get extra credit for making the sort faster? In addition to the one time allocation, you can use a pair of mutually recursive functions to control the direction of merge (array to temp or temp to array), which avoids having to copy data (except merge array to temp of size 1 requires a single element copy from array to temp).

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, using `vector` would be a lot easier, and this is C++. However, if you are just doing this for the sake of learning, then you can dynamically allocate arrays like suggested.

```
int *leftArr = new int[size1];
int *rightArr = new int[size2];

//do stuff

//don't forget to free your memory

delete [] leftArr;
delete [] rightArr;
```

Comment: There may not be a problem, but if the "do stuff" does a `return`, or throws an exception, then that's one very big reason to use `vector` -- the memory will not leak.

Answer (score 0):

The technical equivalent of a variable length array allocates from the stack using alloca (the name may vary), but this is not recommended, since a large array will result in stack overflow.

```
     int * leftArr  = _alloca(size1*sizeof(int));
     int * rightArr = _alloca(size2*sizeof(int));
```

Use new and delete[] as suggested in user3886450's answer.